# How to calculate 2 months from today using php date

Tags: php, date

I have the following code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

This results in `2013-10-26`.

What I need is to obtain the date for two months back. So, for this example, it would be `2013-08-26`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` function only formats given timestamp (second parameter which is current time by default).

You should use `strtotime` function to get date 2 months back adn then pass to `date` as second parameter.

Try this:

```
$date = date("Ymd",strtotime("-2 months"));
```

As you can see, `strtotime` function's parameter is very flexible. You can read more about valid values for `strtotime` in PHP's doc. Take a look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) example:

```
echo date_create()->modify('-2 month')->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/57570).

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution, and i actually prefer this over any, although i think the php basics should get the points.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(" -2 months"));
```